# CompileAssemblyFromFile c# attribute 7.2 failed

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

i had try to compiler code with file, but it had some wrong.
the errors: 
1.`global::ProtoBuf.IExtension global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible.GetExtensionObject(bool createIfMissing)`
no ';' at the end

2.`public string Name { get; set; } = "";` '=' is not allowable

the code attribute is C# 7.2+, my project language version is 7.3, .Net FrameWork 4.6.1, Any ideas?

```
  CodeDomProvider provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
        CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
        parameters.CompilerOptions = "/target:library /optimize /warn:0";
        parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
        parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
        parameters.IncludeDebugInformation = true;
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("protobuf-net.dll");


        string[] csharp_files = Tool.GetAllFileNamesByPath(Options.Global.temp_cs_dir, new string[]{ "cs" }).ToArray<string>();

        CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(parameters, csharp_files);
```

thie cs file is

```
// This file was generated by a tool; you should avoid making direct changes.
// Consider using 'partial classes' to extend these types
// Input: Role.proto

#pragma warning disable CS1591, CS0612, CS3021, IDE1006
namespace DataTable
{

    [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoContract()]
    public partial class Role : global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible
    {
        private global::ProtoBuf.IExtension __pbn__extensionData;
        global::ProtoBuf.IExtension global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible.GetExtensionObject(bool createIfMissing)
            => global::ProtoBuf.Extensible.GetExtensionObject(ref __pbn__extensionData, createIfMissing);

        [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(2)]
        [global::System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue("")]
        public string Name { get; set; } = "";

        [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(3)]
        public bool IsBool { get; set; }

        [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(4, IsPacked = true)]
        public int[] Lst { get; set; }

        [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(5)]
        [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMap]
        public global::System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, string> Dic { get; set; } = new global::System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, string>();

    }

}

#pragma warning restore CS1591, CS0612, CS3021, IDE1006
```

Comment: System.CodeDom uses the legacy C# compiler that is included with the framework.  To use syntax available in later versions you have to bring your own copy of Roslyn.  Consider the Microsoft.Net.Compilers nuget package.

Comment: @HansPassant although *in this specific case* it is probably easier to ask the code-gen tool to use C# 3 syntax, since that is a supported output

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a limitation of CodeDOM not supporting the latest compiler versions? For example, when using `CSharpCodeProvider` you need to manually specify the `"CompilerVersion"` setting, and it only reaches pre-Roslyn levels.

Since you're using "protogen", note that "protogen" has support for down-level compiler versions:

[image]

(it isn't explicit - for the sake of brevity - but things like the `#pragma` changes are *also* handled correctly as you change language version)

I'm guessing C# 3 would be a good choice for CodeDOM.

This can be specified via the web UI, using the command-line tools, or can be specified in a .proto file [using custom options](https://protogen.marcgravell.com/#gc545f903467fd7fa441ad80c5433d331).